# Click outside a bootstrap-vue modal component generates onClick event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap-vue and the b-modal component. The problem I have is with the backdrop event which closes my modal but also fires an onClick event on the container of the component that contains the b-modal.

Here is the container in which I call my custom component that containes the modal :

```
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
...
</thead>
    <tbody v-for="(review, index) in reviews"
           :key="review.review.rId"
           @click="showReviewModal(review.review.rId)">
      <custom-item :review="review"/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

...

methods: {
      showReviewModal(id) {
        this.$root.$emit('bv::show::modal', id);
      }
    },
```

In the intermediate custom component :

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <fv-review-modal :id="review.review.rId" :review="review"/>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Finally in the custom component containing the b-modal :

```
<template>
  <b-modal :ref="id"
           :id="id"
           hide-header
           hide-footer
           :modal-class="['review-modal', 'review-modal__body']">
Bla bla bla</b-modal>
</template>
```

I can disable the click outside the modal but I would like to keep it :).
Besides I thought about reacting to the hide event generated by bootstrap-vue and preventing the default behavior to close the current modal manually and avoid generating the onClick event. I need to test it but I don't like this unelegant solution.

Do you have any idea how to fix that ? Thanks!

EDIT :
The solution was :

```
 <template>
      <tr>
        <fv-review-modal :id="review.review.rId" :review="review" @click.native.stop/>
      </tr>
    </template>
```

Comment: I think you just need to stop propagation of event with something like `<custom-item :review="review" @click.stop />`

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it!

Comment: No does not work :(

Comment: try `@click.native.stop` I think it should work.

Comment: Yes that's it it works!!! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Someone should write up the overall solution so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: Just edited my post with the answer ;)